# Azure App Service / Postgresql high latency

Tags: azure, postgresql, django, latency

We have an very simple Azure App Service application using Django (Python) running in West EU Region. The Service Plan for this Service is P1v2 (production plan). The Postgresql is configure with General purpose, 4cpu, 600 IOPS.

The latency between Azure App Service and Azure Postgresql is High (500ms).

They are in the same region.

The SAME app in AWS beanstalk / PostgreSQL is very fast.

Do you have any tips ?